# Firebase .remove not working; no errors returned

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the following code to remove certain db objects from the firebase database. But, for some reason the `.remove()` is not removing the db objects and surprising there are no errors thrown, and `.then()` is executing as well. Can someone help me with it please?

```
try {
    db1.ref('statements/' + nodeLocation).remove()
       .then(function() {
           console.log ("nodeLocation[" + i + "] " + nodeLocation + " deleted successfully! ");
       }, (err) => {console.log(err)});   
} catch (err) {
    console.log ("Error while deleting!");
    console.log (err);
    console.log("Error:" + err.error_message);
}
```

Comment: show your firebase data model.

Comment: @Hareesh thanks for responding back, but I figured it was a reference issue and fixed as I described in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was no problem with the above code, however, the reference was incorrect due to 'nodeLocation' already including 'statements/' and above code was prefixing it again. Thus, simply replacing  this line of code:

```
db1.ref('statements/' + nodeLocation).remove()
```

with this one:

```
db1.ref(nodeLocation).remove()
```

Worked!